# Node.js POST request has data but in mongoDB I see only the id not the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[image]
As you can see in the picture it saves nothing.
The POST request is working, but the data which I am sending to Backend it is saving only new Object with ID but not the data which I have giving.

I do not have any error or something the status is OK.
I am testing this with Postman.

I will add some code.

This is the model.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const dataModelScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    personalData: {
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        title: String,
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        email: String,
        birthday: String,
        telephone: Number,
        driveLicense: String,
        status: Number,
        employmentType: String,
        job: String,
    },
    skills: {
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        name: String,
        startDate: Number,
        endDate: Number,
        description: String,
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('ModelSchema', dataModelScheme);

module.exports = {
    async store(req, res) {
        const modelData = new ModelData({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            personalData: {
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                firstName: req.body.firstName,
            },
            skills: {
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                name: req.body.name,
            },
        });
        modelData.save().then(result => {
            res.status(201).json({
                message: "Handling POST request to modelData",
                modelData: result
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            res.status(500).json({error: error});
        });
    },
}
```

I am trying with Postman like this.

POST -> http://localhost:5000/data

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = express.Router();
routes.post("/data", ModelDataController.store);
module.exports = routes;
```

This is the JSON file which I am trying to send with request.

```
{
    "personalData": {
        "firstName": "Max"
    },
    "skillks": {
        "name": "Muster"
            }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do `req.body.firstName` instead of `req.body.personalData.firstName`. Same for the `name` property.

What you put in Postman under raw is going to correspond to your `req.body`.

Comment: Which is the best way to do that ?
To change into this ?
`req.body.personalData.firstName` if it is so then the above `personalData` makes no sense ?

Comment: It all depends on how your data looks like. In your case if you send that JSON via postman, you have to use `personalData` because that's how you structured it. If you only pass a single property then you can simply get rid of `personalData`. If you send more data, then you want to structure it in some way by using JSON tree-like representation. Focus on making your data structures readable and easy to follow. (p.s. if this answer solves your issue, don't forget to mark it as solving)

Comment: You have answered in my question and thats worked, but I have another small question if I can.
How it is possible to have more than one Object in Array ?
How would the Controllorer change and the JSON in POST Request. ?

Comment: Standard array of objects looks like this `[{"foo": "bar"}, {"foo": "baz"}]` but bear in mind that it's definitely not recommended to organize your data this way if those objects don't share the same structure.

Comment: Which is the best way then ?
See my another question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364605/node-js-post-request-send-array-of-objects-not-only-object/63365311?noredirect=1#comment112061518_63365311