# Node.js POST request send array of objects not only Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As you can see in the picture it saves nothing. The POST request is working, but the data which I am sending to Backend it is saving only new Object with ID but not the data which I have giving, I mean Array of Objects.

I do not have any error or something the status is OK. I am testing this with Postman.
This is the Postman Post Request[image]

I will add some code.

This is the model.

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
    const dataModelScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        personalData: [{
            _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            title: String,
            firstName: String,
            lastName: String,
            email: String,
            birthday: String,
            telephone: Number,
            driveLicense: String,
            status: Number,
            employmentType: String,
            job: String,
        }],
        career: [{
            _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            name: String,
            startDate: Number,
            endDate: Number,
            description: String,
        }],
        education: [{
            _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            name: String,
            description: String
        }],
        skills: [{
            _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            name: String,
            description: String
        }],
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
    });
    module.exports = mongoose.model('ModelSchema', dataModelScheme);
```

And this is the controller.

```
    async store(req, res) {
        const { user_id } = req.headers;

        const user = await User.findById(user_id);

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'User does not exist'});
        }

        const modelData = new ModelData({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            user: user_id,
            personalData: [{
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                title: req.body.personalData.title,
                firstName: req.body.personalData.firstName,
                lastName: req.body.personalData.lastName,
                email: req.body.personalData.email,
                birthday: req.body.personalData.birthday,
                telephone: req.body.personalData.telephone,
                driveLicense: req.body.personalData.driveLicense,
                status: req.body.personalData.status,
                employmentType: req.body.personalData.employmentType,
                job: req.body.personalData.job,
            }],
            skills: [{
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                name: req.body.skills.name,
                description: req.body.skills.description,
            }],
            education: [{
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                name: req.body.education.name,
                description: req.body.education.description,
            }],
        });
        modelData.save().then(result => {
            res.status(201).json(result);
            console.log(req.body.personalData, "req.body");
            console.log(result, "result");
        }).catch(error => {
            res.status(500).json({error: error});
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are passing only one element for personalData, skills and education when you are creating your model. Try with something like this

```
const modelData = new ModelData({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            user: user_id,
            personalData: req.body.personalData.map(personalData => {
                return {
                    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                    title: personalData.title,
                    firstName: personalData.firstName,
                    lastName: personalData.lastName,
                    email: personalData.email,
                    birthday: personalData.birthday,
                    telephone: personalData.telephone,
                    driveLicense: personalData.driveLicense,
                    status: personalData.status,
                    employmentType: personalData.employmentType,
                    job: personalData.job
                };
            }),
            skills: req.body.skills.map(skill => {
                return {
                    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                    name: skill.name,
                    description: skill.description
                };
            },
            education: req.body.education.map(education => {
                return {
                    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                    name: education.name,
                    description: education.description
                };
            }
        });
```

Comment: How would be then the GET request ?
something like this ?
`async show(req, res) {
        const modelData = await ModelData.find().where({"user": req.params.id}).exec();
        if (!modelData) {
            return res.status(204).json({error: "No Data"});
        }
        return res.status(200).send(modelData);
    }`

Comment: You are almost right:

async show(req, res) {         
 const modelData = await ModelData.find({"user": req.params.id}).exec();         
 if (!modelData) {            
  res.status(204).json({error: "No Data"});   
  return;  
 }        

 res.json(modelData);     
}

Comment: I do have a little question.
How would be than the Interface model in Frontend.
For example.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending an array of objects, but are trying to read them as objects using dot notation. You need read them as arrays by providing the index in brackets. I won't go through all of your properties, but this is the gist of what you need to do.`

```
  const modelData = new ModelData({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        user: user_id,
        personalData: [{
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            title: req.body.personalData[0].title,
            firstName: req.body.personalData[0].firstName,
            lastName: req.body.personalData[0].lastName,
          // DO similar for the rest of your properties
        }],
```

`

Comment: Yeah but what will happen if req.body.personalData[0].title it will not except 0 but 1 ?

Comment: You'll need to use .map() as suggested in another answer or loop over your array.